# beautiful soup, looks for only one pattern

Tags: python, file, beautifulsoup

The problem is that I want this code to find all the links in "input.html" file, but it finds and shows only the first link. Below is the code:

```
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
fd = codecs.open('input.html', 'r')

def clean(html): 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        link.extract()
        text = link.get('href')
        return text
```

Comment: don't `return` until you get all links.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the text at the end of the loop which iterates only once. Do this:

```
def clean(html): 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    links = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        link.extract()
        text = link.get('href')
        links.append(text)
    return links
```

Also instead of a function you can have a simple list comprehension:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
links = [link.extract().get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
fd = codecs.open('input.html', 'r')

text = []

def clean(html): 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        link.extract()
        text.append(link.get('href'))
    return text
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting a link at end of the loop.
You may use this:

```
def clean(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    hrefs = soup.find_all('a')
    links = []
    if hrefs:
        for href in hrefs:
            href.extract()
            link = href.get('href')
            links.append(link)
        return links
```